# How to sort array inside tuple stored in dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary

I have such dictionary of tuples:

```
var items = [(String, [LogSymptomTemp])]()
```

I'm using it to display grouped table view with sections.

How can I sort items of `LogSymptomTemp` array by severity?

```
struct LogSymptomTemp {

var symptomId = String()
var symptomName = String()
var trackedInRow = Int()
var severity = Int() }
```

As temp solution, I'm sorting inside my `tableView cellForRowAt` method, but that's not a place to do that:

```
let logItems = items[indexPath.section].1

let finalList = logItems.sorted(by: { $0.severity > $1.severity })
```

I'm used to simple data structs and I can do simple sorting, but I'm struggling with this one, as it's not so obvious for me.

Comment: That is not a dictionary; that is effectively a [KeyValuePairs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyvaluepairs). Which do you need?

Comment: Ok, sorry, I named it wrong, but I still need to sort items in [LogSymptomTemp]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
for var item in items {
   item.1.sort(by: { $0.severity > $1.severity })
 }
```

making each item as variable helps in mutating each item as sort mutates the array present in tuple.

Comment: Thanks, I also came up with such solution, but how do I put that item back to corresponding key?

Comment: sort mutates itself while sorted returns a result.

Comment: figured it out, if you can extend your answer with latest comment I can mark it as accepted, thanks!